# Upgrade wall heater inside Cadet FWC can

Tags: walls, heater, retrofit

The Cadet FW wall heater with 1984 manufacturing date just shorted as I was cleaning it last night, ruining the coils. Is there a product out there for which I can reuse the existing FWC wall can? Google hasn't been helpful.

The inside dimensions of the wall can are approximately 7.5" x 14.5"

Comment: Why were you cleaning it with the power on?  Unless they sell replacement/repair coils for it, think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Search "Cadet FW conversion kit".

You should find options for you to install a modern Cadet core into your heater frame.